# java.lang.StackOverflowError while adding new activity in activity group

Tags: android, activitygroup, android-tabactivity

I am getting **`stackoverflow error`**

**My layout structure as below**

```
<TabActivity>
    <tab1><Activity name="home">
    <tab2><Activitygroup><activity name="XYZ">
                <activity name="options">
                <activity name="thankYou">
    <tab3>
        <TabActivity>
            <tab3.1><Activitygroup><activities name="PQR">
            <tab3.2><activity name="today">
            <tab3.3><activity name="history">
            <tab3.4><Activitygroup>
                    <activity name="reOrder"> from this I will open 
                    <Activity name="options">
        <TabActivity>
    <tab4><Activitygroup><activities name="ABC">
    <tab5><Activity name="setting">
<TabActivity>
```

I am getting error when I am in `tab3.4`.
I have one activity in Activitygroup and now I am adding new activity in this activitygroup when 
next button clicked on first activity in activitygroup of `tab3.4`.

I debugged it and check that till the onResume() it is working fine but after that it is firing error.
Before getting error also I can see the new activity.

Also if I open another activity it is working fine. At that time It is working perfactly.

**Stacktrace**

```
11-23 07:06:24.912: WARN/dalvikvm(1783): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001b188)
11-23 07:06:24.912: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783): java.lang.StackOverflowError
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.text.Styled.measureText(Styled.java:371)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.text.Layout.measureText(Layout.java:1601)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.text.Layout.getLineMax(Layout.java:655)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.text.Layout.getLineWidth(Layout.java:637)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.widget.TextView.getRightFadingEdgeStrength(TextView.java:6713)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6608)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6641)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6641)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1529)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1531)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1258)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6538)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1830)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1349)
11-23 07:06:24.943: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1783):     at android.view.ViewRoo
```

Please help me out from this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am afraid you will need any other workaround instead of nesting `ActivityGroup` in another `ActivityGroup`
because android doesn't support too many nested `ViewGroup` may be some memory issues.

and some times these tabs work perfectly on Emulator but will show defiantly `StackOverflowException` while deployed on real devices.

So the simplest is to change `Activity` flow (e.g getting child `ActivityGroup` out of parent `ActivityGroup` and show it in entire screen)

[For further see here, answer by Romain Guy](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/4736c606a8aa6b95#)

Comment: Yeah you are right it is the problem of multiple hierarchy of view group.I removed some inner layout and now it is working fine.Thanks.

Comment: @Dharmendra: and please make sure your code run also on real devices.