# Android uncaught exception

Tags: android, android-logcat

i installed my app in a tablet and it works but when i tried to install my app in my phone this errors shows up in the logcat and i don't know what causes it, anyone encountered this?

```
01-03 13:38:12.657: W/dalvikvm(2719): threadid=3: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e170)
01-03 13:38:12.657: E/AndroidRuntime(2719): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.traininghandouts.app/com.traininghandouts.app.Login}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2496)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2512)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:119)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1863)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #48: Error inflating class <unknown>
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:618)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1622)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at com.traininghandouts.app.Login.onCreate(Login.java:74)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2459)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     ... 11 more
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:105)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     ... 22 more
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719): Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceValue(AssetManager.java:186)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:887)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:579)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:160)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1690)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:580)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:160)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1690)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:580)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:160)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1690)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:580)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(StateListDrawable.java:160)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:788)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:729)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1690)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:580)
01-03 13:38:12.767: E/AndroidRuntime(2719):     at android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable.inflate(S
```

what should i do to fix this?

Comment: i think problem with API that you have used in your app. which API you are using in your app. ? if some of classes included later version of SDK and you are trying to used that in lower version of SDK. I am not sure but you can change the API that is compatible with you phone and check error if any.

Comment: android:minsdkversion="4" built="8"

Comment: i tried to install the app before, and it runs well it's just that now it doesn't work and force closes, shows this errors

Answer (score 0):

Two traces, 1) XML Inflater 2) Stackoverflow suggesting, you have too many nested views in your app (which is not well supported by android). Please see this discussion for more details.[stackoverflow error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8238134/java-lang-stackoverflowerror-while-adding-new-activity-in-activity-group)

You may need to reconsider your view group hierarchy.

Comment: i'm kinda new to android and i'm kinda lost there